# How does Google Chrome resolve an URL starting with two slashes and a number?

Tags: html, google-chrome, url

I got this situation:

I generate static HTML pages through Jekyll, unfortunately, I set the `config.yml` `_baseUrl = /` , so when it's down, the `href` in the `index.html` becomes:

```
<a href="//2016/01/10/first-posts.html">my first post</a>
```

When I click the link in `index.html`:

> http://localhost:4000/index.html

it turns out to be a reserve address:

> http://0.0.7.224/01/10/first-posts.html

Then I had some tests and found out that `//1` represent `0.0.0.1`, and when a number comes after `//` in the URL, it represents a reserve IP address.

It works right in Safari. Why does Chrome act like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slash and dot (`/.`) before your URL address, like this:

```html
<a href="/.//1">this links to //1</a>
```

Comment: This definitely  will work.I just wonder why chrome has that setting,it confuse me what it can use for.

Comment: It  just seems not very elegant,anyway i'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt

> **5.  Examples and Recommended Practice**
>
> Within an object with a well-defined base URL of
>
> ```
> Base: <URL:http://a/b/c/d;p?q#f>
> ```
>
> the relative URLs would be resolved as follows:
>
> **5.1.  Normal Examples**
>
> […]
>
> ```
> //g        = <URL:http://g>
> ```

it point out `//2016` represent net_loc not path.